# Improve performance of this query finding nearby locations

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, postgis, nearest-neighbor

I am trying to execute this SQL, but the query is really slow (almost 2 hours), It's actually querying 1 million records (property_ids), that's why it's slow. But can someone suggest me a strategy to make this query faster, may be doing this in batches etc.

```
WITH properties AS
    (SELECT sid FROM prod.vw_property WHERE status = 'active')
SELECT p.sid,
      -- active list count means not expired
      count(*) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_count_active,

      -- 30d list count DOES include those that are now expired (ie. listed and expired quickly within 30d)
      count(*) FILTER (WHERE (cl.listed_on >= ((now())::date - '30 days'::interval))) AS list_count_30d,

      -- All other aggregates should only include active (not expired) rew listings
      avg(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_avg,
      percentile_cont(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL)::numeric(12, 2) AS list_price_median,
      min(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_min,
      max(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_max,
      avg((cl.list_price / (cl.interior_size_sqft)::numeric)) FILTER (WHERE (cl.interior_size_sqft > 100 AND cl.expired_at IS NULL)) AS list_price_per_sqft_avg,
      percentile_cont((0.50)::double precision) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY (((cl.list_price / (cl.interior_size_sqft)::numeric))::double precision))
          FILTER (WHERE (cl.interior_size_sqft > 100) AND cl.expired_at IS NULL)::numeric(12, 2) AS list_price_per_sqft_median,

      -- Show up to 10 closest listings that were used to get the aggregate numbers
      (array_agg(cl.rew_properties_id ORDER BY (st_distance(p.location, cl.location)))
           FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL))[1:10] AS closest_rew_properties_ids
     FROM prod.vw_property p
     INNER JOIN prod.vw_comparable_listing cl
     ON
       ((((COALESCE(upper(p.land_area_sqft), 0))::numeric >= cl.land_size_sqft_lower)
         AND ((COALESCE(upper(p.land_area_sqft), 0))::numeric <= cl.land_size_sqft_upper)
         AND (((upper(p.interior_area_finished_sqft))::numeric >= cl.interior_size_sqft_lower)
              AND ((upper(p.interior_area_finished_sqft))::numeric <= cl.interior_size_sqft_upper))
         AND (((p.num_bed)::numeric >= cl.num_bed_lower) AND ((p.num_bed)::numeric <= cl.num_bed_upper))
         -- Within 2km
         AND st_dwithin(p.location, cl.location, 2000) AND (
          CASE
              WHEN (p.rew_property_type = ANY (ARRAY['duplex'::prod.rew_property_type_enum, 'fourplex'::prod.rew_property_type_enum, 'triplex'::prod.rew_property_type_enum])) THEN 'townhouse'::prod.rew_property_type_enum
              ELSE p.rew_property_type
          END = cl.property_type_group)))
     JOIN properties ps ON ps.sid = p.sid
     GROUP BY 1;
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated. Also would like to add that AWS RDS large instance was at 52% due to this query.

Here is the Query plan:

```
QUERY PLAN
GroupAggregate  (cost=26994787.36..26994787.70 rows=1 width=212)
  Group Key: p.sid
  CTE properties
    ->  Seq Scan on property p_1  (cost=0.00..1260715.24 rows=2807666 width=4)
          Filter: ((latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (longitude IS NOT NULL) AND (rew_geographies_id IS NOT NULL) AND (status = 'active'::prod.source_record_status_type))
  ->  Sort  (cost=25734072.12..25734072.13 rows=1 width=122)
        Sort Key: p.sid
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.54..25734072.11 rows=1 width=122)
              Join Filter: (p.sid = ps.sid)
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.54..25642822.97 rows=1 width=122)
                    Join Filter: (pt.sid = p.property_type_sid)
"                    Filter: (CASE WHEN (pt.rew_property_type = ANY ('{duplex,fourplex,triplex}'::prod.rew_property_type_enum[])) THEN 'townhouse'::prod.rew_property_type_enum ELSE pt.rew_property_type END = cl.property_type_group)"
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.54..25641727.79 rows=36 width=130)
                          ->  Seq Scan on vw_comparable_listing cl  (cost=0.00..881.04 rows=28404 width=100)
                          ->  Index Scan using property_location_ix on property p  (cost=0.54..902.71 rows=1 width=96)
"                                Index Cond: (location && _st_expand(cl.location, '2000'::double precision))"
"                                Filter: ((latitude IS NOT NULL) AND (longitude IS NOT NULL) AND (rew_geographies_id IS NOT NULL) AND ((num_bed)::numeric >= cl.num_bed_lower) AND ((num_bed)::numeric <= cl.num_bed_upper) AND ((COALESCE(upper(land_area_sqft), 0))::numeric >= cl.land_size_sqft_lower) AND ((COALESCE(upper(land_area_sqft), 0))::numeric <= cl.land_size_sqft_upper) AND ((upper(interior_area_finished_sqft))::numeric >= cl.interior_size_sqft_lower) AND ((upper(interior_area_finished_sqft))::numeric <= cl.interior_size_sqft_upper) AND (cl.location && _st_expand(location, '2000'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(location, cl.location, '2000'::double precision, true))"
                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..57.41 rows=1361 width=8)
                          ->  Seq Scan on property_type pt  (cost=0.00..50.61 rows=1361 width=8)
              ->  CTE Scan on properties ps  (cost=0.00..56153.32 rows=2807666 width=4)
```

Comment: Please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Also, the CTE ("with properties as...") is likely not helping performance any there, could you try incorporating it into the body of the query?

Comment: Consider instructions in https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Many parentheses are just distracting noise. Several casts seem unnecessary.
Most importantly, the CTE seems to do nothing useful, remove it and just keep the `WHERE` condition:

```
SELECT p.sid,
       -- active list count means not expired
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_count_active,

       -- 30d list count DOES include those that are now expired (ie. listed and expired quickly within 30d)
       count(*) FILTER (WHERE cl.listed_on >= now()::date - 30) AS list_count_30d,

       -- All other aggregates should only include active (not expired) rew listings
       avg(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_avg,
       percentile_cont(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL)::numeric(12, 2) AS list_price_median,
       min(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_min,
       max(cl.list_price) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL) AS list_price_max,
       avg(cl.list_price / cl.interior_size_sqft::numeric) FILTER (WHERE (cl.interior_size_sqft > 100 AND cl.expired_at IS NULL)) AS list_price_per_sqft_avg,
       percentile_cont(0.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cl.list_price / cl.interior_size_sqft::double precision)
          FILTER (WHERE cl.interior_size_sqft > 100 AND cl.expired_at IS NULL)::numeric(12, 2) AS list_price_per_sqft_median,

       -- Show up to 10 closest listings that were used to get the aggregate numbers
       (array_agg(cl.rew_properties_id ORDER BY st_distance(p.location, cl.location) FILTER (WHERE cl.expired_at IS NULL)))[1:10] AS closest_rew_properties_ids
FROM   prod.vw_property           p
JOIN   prod.vw_comparable_listing cl ON ST_DWITHIN(p.location, cl.location, 2000)  -- within 2km
WHERE  COALESCE(p.land_area_sqft, 0) BETWEEN cl.land_size_sqft_lower     AND cl.land_size_sqft_upper
AND    p.interior_area_finished_sqft BETWEEN cl.interior_size_sqft_lower AND cl.interior_size_sqft_upper
AND    p.num_bed                     BETWEEN cl.num_bed_lower            AND cl.num_bed_upper
AND    CASE WHEN p.rew_property_type = ANY ('{duplex,fourplex,triplex}'::prod.rew_property_type_enum[])
          THEN cl.property_type_group = 'townhouse'::prod.rew_property_type_enum
          ELSE cl.property_type_group = p.rew_property_type
       END
AND    p.status = 'active'
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`upper` in `(COALESCE(upper(p.land_area_sqft), 0))::numeric >= cl.land_size_sqft_lower` doesn't do anything useful. Nor (probably) does the cast to `numeric`. (And I am not sure you need `COALESCE`. Can the range `[cl.land_size_sqft_lower, cl.land_size_sqft_upper]` contain `0`?)

Assuming that `p.land_area_sqft` etc *are* of some numeric type, not `text`, else you need to add back casts - and reconsider data types of your table columns.

`(array_agg(...))[1:10]` can be needlessly expensive if there can be substantially more than 10 elements in the resulting array. A *custom aggregate function* that stops adding elements after nr. 10 helps is this case.

You already have an index on `property(location)`. If you are only interested in the 10 closest ("nearest") locations, consider and actual **"nearest neighbour"** search:

- [Unique assignment of closest points between two tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517386/unique-assignment-of-closest-points-between-two-tables/34521492#34521492)